# How to retrieve the object data from Custom metadata types

Tags: apex, data-loader, configuration, custom-metadata, workbench

I am trying to retrieve the records from custom metadata types objects but in data loader it is not showing up

Comment: Custom metadata types records are not "data", this is "metadata", so you need to use Metadata API in one or another way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

In the Salesforce-provided Dataloader, you need to check "Show all Salesforce Objects" for Custom Metadata Types (ending in `__mdt`) to appear.

Note that this only works for exporting data. Custom Metadata Types will not appear if you try to insert/update/upsert/delete/hard delete because Custom Metadata Type records are *metadata*, not data.

Answer (score 1):

The Data Loader, as far as I can tell, does not support Custom Metadata (and we've been given no indication if this will be available in the future). In fact, custom metadata isn't "real" data, and is actually documented in the Metadata API documentation. You could choose to use Ant and build the appropriate files that way, or you can follow the other instructions for simply loading this metadata.

Instead, Use the custom metadata loader to bulk load records to your custom metadata types from a .csv file. The custom metadata loader lets you load up to 200 records with a single call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about data loader but other alternative and and the simplest way to do it via VS code using org browser(considering you have already configured Salesforce CLI and Salesforce extension pack).